# How to avoid using System.String with Rfc2898DeriveBytes in C#

Tags: passwords, web-application, .net, asp.net-core

I am creating a .NET core webapp in C# that takes in a user password and hashes it to be stored on a server. I'm using `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` along with a randomly generated salt. I've read, however, that I should avoid using strings in the entire process since strings cannot be removed from memory. I know that .NET core has a `PasswordBox` that keeps the password as a `SecureString`, but `SecureString`s cannot be converted to a byte array to be passed to `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`'s constructor without a great deal of shenanigans.

Since the webapp is only going to run on my server, can I just convert the `SecureString` back to a string as soon as it has been passed into my webapp? If an attacker manages to access the server's RAM to search for an undeleted string, there's probably very little I can do to protect anything to begin with.

If I should still go through with using `SecureStrings`, what are the best practices for hashing it to be stored?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using SecureString correctly is difficult, and protects against a threat surface that is unlikely for most use cases. As you say, if an attacker can read your memory, you have other problems. I would advise to use normal strings instead of SecureString, unless you are worried by attackers [carrying liquid nitrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack#Technical_details) with physical access to your server.

If you really want to use SecureStrings, you should P/Invoke the Windows crypto API so that you have control over memory. I have an example in my blog post [Comparing secure strings in .NET](https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2017/11/08/comparing-securestrings-in-dotnet/).

Comment: No liquid nitrogen needed: there software (Heartbleed) vulnerabilities that allow reading parts of RAM, and hardware vulnerabilities like Spectre can be exploited in a cloud environment. But I agree that it's rather unlikely and not something most web apps should be concerned with.

Comment: What's the thing about liquid nitrogen?

Comment: In a [cold boot attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack#Technical_details), memory can be cooled with liquid nitrogen so that data persists while moving the DRAM modules to another computer to read the data.

Answer (score 48):

The .NET Core team specifically recommends against using **SecureString** for new development. See the [**SecureString** documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> We don't recommend that you use the SecureString class for new development. For more information, see **SecureString shouldn't be used** on GitHub.

as well as [the team's reasoning on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md):

> ### Motivation
>
> - The purpose of `SecureString` is to avoid having secrets stored in the process
>     memory as plain text.
> - However, even on Windows, `SecureString` doesn't exist as an OS concept.
>
>   - It just makes the window getting the plain text shorter; it doesn't fully
>       prevent it as .NET still has to convert the string to a plain text
>       representation.
>   - The benefit is that the plain text representation doesn't hang around
>       as an instance of `System.String` -- the lifetime of the native buffer is
>       shorter.
> - The contents of the array is unencrypted except on .NET Framework.
>
>   - In .NET Framework, the contents of the internal char array is encrypted.
>       .NET doesn't support encryption in all environments, either
>       due to missing APIs or key management issues.

Comment: Very interesting, great first answer! It should be noted that process memory in general is only really an attack surface if an attacker is able to get access to it - something that is generally not part of the threat model of a web application, unless on a shared host.

Comment: @MechMK1 That is mentioned in the other answer already, I just wanted to add the official recommendation, too.

Comment: The quoted part says nothing about recommending against using SecureString. Could you please quote (or bold) the relevant parts.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh It's in the first link and doesn't really say more than that they don't recommend it for new development and contains a link to the quoted part.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh I assume because it's a huge pain to work with, and in the end it has to end up in plaintext anyways, so there is little use to it

Comment: Maybe because you can ask the debugger (WinDbg + SOS) or profiler for objects of type `SecureString`, which makes password discovery even easier than using regular strings. With some IL injection, it's a [one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25751722/480982) to decode the password.